# How record video using javaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

My code is here. I'm using code by Dr. Andrew Davison

```
private IplImage picGrab(FrameGrabber grabber, int ID) {
    IplImage im = null;
    try {

        FrameRecorder rec = FrameRecorder.createDefault("vid.avi", 240, 360);
        rec.setVideoCodec(CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
        rec.setVideoBitrate(16);
        rec.setFrameRate(25);
        rec.setFormat("avi");
        rec.setPixelFormat(1);
        rec.start();

        im = grabber.grab();

        // take a snap
        //   cvSaveImage("capture"+captureNo+".jpg", im);
        rec.record(im);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Problem grabbing image for camera " + ID);
    }
    return im;
}
```

And follow exception is occurred.

```
com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: cvWriteFrame(): Could not record frame
Problem grabbing image for camera 0
Initializing OpenCV motion detector...
    at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameRecorder.record(OpenCVFrameRecorder.java:91)
    at photocapture.MotionPanel.picGrab(MotionPanel.java:181)
    at photocapture.MotionPanel.run(MotionPanel.java:100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: how fix this error. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check your default frame size.. I usually get this error when the default frame size is less than the set frame size

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `FrameGrabber` is valid. The error message is a clue that setting it up might have failed.

The error message informs you did something like:

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
```

but device 0 is not your camera.

In the beginning of the method you should add a safety check:

```
 private IplImage picGrab(FrameGrabber grabber, int ID) {

    if (grabber == null) 
    {
        System.out.println("!!! Bad OpenCVFrameGrabber");
        return null;
    }

    // ...
```